# Numpy; reshape 1d number sequence to 2d number sequences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Soppose I have a numpy array like this:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,17])
```

And I want the following result:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [10, 11, 12]
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

Another example would be:

```
arr = np.array([3900, 3901, 3902, 3903, 3964, 3965, 3966, 3967, 4028, 4029, 4030, 4031, 4092, 4093, 4094, 4095])
```

Result:

```
array([[3900, 3901, 3902, 3903],
       [3964, 3965, 3966, 3967],
       [4028, 4029, 4030, 4031],
       [4092, 4093, 4094, 4095]])
```

These 1d arrays are generated dynamically with different length.

```
result = arr.reshape((?,?))
```

The resulting array must consist of rows that are in sequential order. When the sequence breaks, that's a new row.

Comment: There are 4 number sequences: 012, 567, 101112, 151617. So I need 4 rows

Comment: The solution must find the sequences

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know if you don't mention it?

Comment: What is "a sequence" in these arrays?

Comment: Yes, but you STILL haven't stated the key requirement, that the array must consist of rows that are in sequential order.  When the sequence breaks, that's a new row.  That is THE key requirement, and you haven't said it.

Comment: The amount of sequences is ambiguous. In the second example the array could also be (8, 2)

Comment: @isedgar Do you need a squared matrix always? 3x3 4x4?

Comment: @Tim Roberts exactly! how to do this

Comment: @Wagner de Andrade Perin no

Comment: If your result is always going to be a square matrix, the sequence pattern doesn't matter.  There is only one square root for any length of the original array (and only a subset of those are whole numbers).  If the sequence is not regular (i.e. doesn't break after a constant number of items) then a numpy array will not be able to store the result in all scenarios.  If the sequence does break at regular intervals, then there are specific rows/columns combinations that correspond to the factors of the size of the original array.  In short, if the sequence matters, numpy won't work.

Comment: @isedgar  - You do it by hand, one at a time.  Loop until k[i+1] != k[i]+1.   Can you assume that, once you have found the first break, all of the other rows are the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming consecutive values with breaks at regular intervals**, like in your two examples. You can use `np.diff(arr)` to compute the difference between successive values and `np.argmax(np.diff(arr)!=1)` to identify the index of the first "break" in the increasing sequence. The width of the reshape is this number + 1.

We can now use `reshape`:

```
arr = np.array([3900, 3901, 3902, 3903, 3964, 3965, 3966, 3967, 4028, 4029, 4030, 4031, 4092, 4093, 4094, 4095])

arr.reshape((-1, (1+np.argmax(np.diff(arr)!=1))))
```

output:

```
array([[3900, 3901, 3902, 3903],
       [3964, 3965, 3966, 3967],
       [4028, 4029, 4030, 4031],
       [4092, 4093, 4094, 4095]])
```

Comment: Not working with np.array([0,1,2,5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,17])

Comment: @isedgar yes it is. What is your output?

Comment: I edited the first example. Your code doesn't gives the correct result

Comment: @mozway Check the output for the first array and you will see, that you have to flip the order of appearance for the reshaping.

Comment: @mozway It has to be `arr.reshape((-1, 1+np.argmax(np.diff(arr)!=1))`

Answer (score 1):

The following works with both arrays, but would require that the rows have all the same length.

```
# get indices where sequence breaks
indices = np.where(np.diff(arr)!=1)[0]

# get lengths of the sequences (except one is missing)
row_length = np.diff(indices)

# check if row length matches
if np.all(row_length == row_length[0]):
    reshaped = arr.reshape((-1, row_length[0]))
    print(arr)
    print(reshaped)
else:
    print('unable to reshape, sequences have different lengths')
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  2  5  6  7 10 11 12 15 16 17]
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 5  6  7]
 [10 11 12]
 [15 16 17]]

[3900 3901 3902 3903 3964 3965 3966 3967 4028 4029 4030 4031 4092 4093
 4094 4095]
[[3900 3901 3902 3903]
 [3964 3965 3966 3967]
 [4028 4029 4030 4031]
 [4092 4093 4094 4095]]
```